# Absolute fastest way to get ID of underlying jQuery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering about the fastest way to get the ID of an element which wrapped in a cached jQuery object. I have *n* number of elements to iterate over and so I want to make sure I'm using the most efficient code possible.

Which one of these is fastest/any other suggestions? Any cost/benefit analysis would be much appreciated.

```
//cached jquery object using .attr()    
$myElement.attr("id");

//getting the native JS element and getting the ID that way
$myElement[0].getAttribute('id');
```

Thanks!

Comment: `$myElement[0].id` might be even faster. You should make a http://jsperf.com/ test

Comment: In modern jQuery `.prop()` would be better than `.attr()`, but just getting at the raw DOM element and accessing the "id" property is probably the best thing. The differences however are tiny and for almost all applications not worth worrying about at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following way is the fastest:

```
var id = $myElement[0].id;
```

Here you don't call any functions, just address the object properties.

[image]

**JSPerf:** http://jsperf.com/jquery-get-object-property

Comment: Thanks for the jsperf, the graphs don't lie!